# Counting fundamental frequency with yin method in C#

Tags: c#, signal-processing, frequency, voice

I need to count the fundamental frequency with yin algorithm in C#.

I have an array (data[44100]) which contains the amplitude of a 1 sec long 250Hz sinus wave. Here is my code:

```
int t = 0;                    //starting point of the window
int w = data.Length / 25;     //the end of the window so the size of the window is 40msec
int rmax = 0;                 //the maximum of the correlation function
int period = 0;               //the period of the sinus

for (int tau = 0; tau < w; tau++)
{ 
    int r = 0;
    for (int j = t + 1; j < (t + w); j++)
    {
       r = r + (data[j] * data[j + tau]);
    }     
    if (r > rmax)
    {
       rmax = r;
       period = tau;
    }
}

float time = (float)period/44100;
float freq = 1.0f / time;
System.Console.WriteLine(freq);
```

I should get 250 for the frequency but something goes wrong. The values in the array are good, i checked it in excel and the period was as it should be. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

You are including a lag of zero in your autocorrelation function, and a signal correlates perfectly with itself with zero lag.  You also stop (tau < w) before reaching a lag of one period, where a sin wave would have its next autocorrelation peak.

Try starting with a lag of half your expected period and stepping to 1.5x your expected period.

Comment: I made it but it is still wrong. Now i counted the period of the other segments and at least they are tha same as the first period. But the results depends on the size of the window. Is that normal?

Comment: A rectangular window that contains any signal not strictly periodic in that window width will produce "spectral leakage" artifacts.  Is that what you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between your code and your comment.

1 sec / 25 would be 0.04 sec not 0.4 sec.